# Adding properties to a bitmap object that's created by calling another method within a constructor

Tags: c#, image, graphics, bitmap

I have a method that takes in a `bitmap` object and overlays dates and times strings over it and returns that new `bitmap`. The code is below.

```
    public static Bitmap overlayBitmap(Bitmap sourceBMP, int width, int height, List<String> times, List<String> dates, IEnumerable<Color> colors) {

        // Determine the new width
        float newWidth = width + (width / 3.0f);
        float newHeight = height + (height / 3.0f);

        // Intelligent vertical + horizontal text distance calculator
        float verticalDistance = height / (times.Count - 1.0f);
        float horizontalDistance = width / (dates.Count - 1.0f);

        Bitmap result = new Bitmap((int)newWidth, (int)newHeight);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result)) {

            // Background color
            Brush brush = new SolidBrush(colors.First());
            g.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
            g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;

            // Times text configs
            StringFormat stringFormatTimes = new StringFormat();
            stringFormatTimes.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            stringFormatTimes.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            Font drawFontY = new Font("Whitney", newHeight / 70);

            // Dates text configs
            StringFormat stringFormatDates = new StringFormat();
            stringFormatDates.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            stringFormatTimes.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            stringFormatDates.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical;
            Font drawFontX = new Font("Whitney", newHeight / 70);

            // Location of times text
            for (int i = 0; i < times.Count; i++) {
                if (i % determineIncrementTimes(times.Count) == 0) {
                    g.DrawString(times[i], drawFontX, Brushes.White, (((newWidth - width) / 2) / 2), ((newHeight - height) / 2) + (verticalDistance * i), stringFormatTimes);
                }
            }

            // Location of dates text
            for (int i = 0; i < dates.Count; i++) {
                if (i % determineIncrementDates(dates.Count) == 0) {
                    g.DrawString(dates[i], drawFontY, Brushes.White, ((newWidth - width) / 2) + (horizontalDistance * i), ((newHeight - height) / 2) + height, stringFormatDates);
                }
            }

            // New X and Y Position of the sourceBMP within the new BMP.
            int XPos = width / 6;
            int YPos = height / 6;

            // Int -> Float casting for the outline
            float fXPos = width / 6.0f;
            float fYPos = height / 6.0f;

            float fWidth = width / 1.0f;
            float fHeight = height / 1.0f;

            // Draw new image at the position width/6 and height/6 with the size at width and height
            g.DrawImage(sourceBMP, fXPos, fYPos, fWidth, fHeight);
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.White, fXPos, fYPos, fWidth, fHeight); // white outline
            g.Dispose();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

My concern is, I would like to be able, for the next developer, to easily access and set particular values that currently I've only "hardcoded" in. An example being the x-position of the time text calculated via this snippet of code:

`(((newWidth - width) / 2) / 2)`

Realistically I'd like to have the developer be able to access and/or set this value through simply typing in:

`something.XPos = [someFloat];`

How my method above is used (is pseudo-code) is as the following:

```
private readonly Bitmap _image;
private readonly Bitmap _overlayedImage;

public myConstructor(int someInputValues){
    // some code that generates the first bitmap called _image
    _newImage = overlayImage(_image, ....);
}
```

For reference this is the image drawn:

[image]

My question is - since some values need to be casted and initialized first, can I set my instance variables at the end of the method, before the closing brace?

Comment: You could just have a property that uses the getter to Build and return your Bitmap object

Comment: I understand the gist of what you mean, but can you elaborate, perhaps with some psuedo-code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Bitmap overlayBitmap
{
    get
    {
        // Build bitmap overlay
        return overlayBitmapOutput;
    }
...
}
```

[Edit: Answer Insufficient >> Wait]

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly we are creating a new class (within the same page of code), and inside this new class is a getter that returns overlayBitmapOutput?

Comment: Actually, rereading what you are looking for, let me rewrite.  sec.

Comment: Sorry had a call.  Just so I'm clear, you want the user to be able to access your static method.  That seems simple on it's face var OutputFromMethod = File.ReadAllText(someFile); // ReadAllText is a static method in a public class, some file is a text resource used as a param.  Whay can't you just do that?  Am I overthinking this?

Comment: Hey Zombie. I did a bit more fiddling in my code, let me see if I can explain this correctly. Using `map.xPosTime` (`map` is an object from my construct) I can get the x-axis position of the time strings. `xPosTime = (((newWidth - width) / 2) / 2);` With that said, I would like to have the programmer also add values to `xPosTime`, so something like `xPosTime = (((newWidth - width) / 2) / 2) + someFloatValue;` What would I do, properties-wise, with `someFloatValue`? I've also changed the method to a non-static method, so I could assign instance variables. They were in the same class anyways.

Comment: Additionally, I would like to add that, I would not like the `(((newWidth - width) / 2) / 2)` value to be changed; only the `someFloatValue`, since `(((newWidth - width) / 2) / 2)` intelligently scales the positioning of the text depending on those two parameters inside. `someFloatValue` essentially allows the user to slide the text left or right based on that anchor position, if that makes sense.

Comment: The user can insert as many params in the static method call as you dictate.
    
    var fileToString = File.ReadAllText(someFile, param0, param1, ...)
    var UniqueBitmap = YourBitmapClass.YourStaticMethod(param, param, param, ...)

Wouldn't that work?

Comment: What I mean is params within the instance variable - unless I should just create a new instance var?

Comment: What I mean is that they wouldn't create an instance of the class, the method would simply return the bitmap object.  the var would hold the output of the method, not a new instance of the class

Comment: jsut have the user pass in the stringFormatDates, stringFormatTimes as params, then assign the params to variables in the method.  that way the user only interacts with the BitmapBuilder and gets a bitmap output from the method